# Draw RGB pixel array to DirectX-11 render view

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11

Given an array of RBG pixels that updates every frame (e.g. 1024x1024), a `ID3D11RenderTargetView`, `ID3D11Device` and `ID3D11DeviceContext`, what's the easiest way to draw these pixels to the render view?

I've been working the angle of creating a vertex buffer for a square (two triangles), trying to make pixels be a proper texture, and figuring out how to make a shader reference the texture sampler. I've been following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/applying-textures-to-primitives .... But to be honest, I don't see how this tutorial has shaders that even reference the texture data ([shaders defined on the proceeding tutorial, here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/creating-shaders-and-drawing-primitives)).

I am a total DirectX novice, but I am writing a plugin for an application where I am given a directx11 device/view/context, and need to fill it with my pixel data. Many thanks!

Comment: You can also use Direct2D which lives over Direct3D and can make your life easier for common 2D operations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-portal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*IF* you can make sure your staging resource matches the exact resolution and format of the render target you are given:

1. Create a staging resource
2. Map the staging resource, and copy your data into it.
3. Unmap the staging resource
4. Use`GetResource` on the RTV to get the resource
5. `CopyResource` from your staging to that resource.

Otherwise, *IF* you can count on [Direct3D Hardware Feature level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro) 10.0 or better, the easiest way would be:

1. Create a texture with `USAGE_DYNAMIC`.
2. Map it and copy your data into the texture.
3. Unmap the resource
4. Render the dynamic texture as a 'full-screen' quad using the 'big-triangle' self-generation trick in the vertex shader:

```
SamplerState PointSampler : register(s0);
Texture2D<float4> Texture : register(t0);

struct Interpolators
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

Interpolators main(uint vI : SV_VertexId)
{
    Interpolators output;

    // We use the 'big triangle' optimization so you only Draw 3 verticies instead of 4.
    float2 texcoord = float2((vI << 1) & 2, vI & 2);
    output.TexCoord = texcoord;
    output.Position = float4(texcoord.x * 2 - 1, -texcoord.y * 2 + 1, 0, 1);

    return output;
}
```

and a pixel shader of:

```
float4 main(Interpolators In) : SV_Target0
{
    return Texture.Sample(PointSampler, In.TexCoord);
}
```

Then draw with:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* textures[1] = { texture };
context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, textures);

// You need a sampler object.
context->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &sampler);

// Depending on your desired result, you may need state objects here
context->OMSetBlendState(nullptr, nullptr, 0xffffffff);
context->OMSetDepthStencilState(nullptr, 0);
context->RSSetState(nullptr);

context->IASetInputLayout(nullptr);
contet->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
Draw(3, 0);
```

For full source for the "Full Screen Quad" drawing, see [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/Kits/ATGTK/FullScreenQuad).